# Psycopg inserting only two rows on data being passed via for loop

Tags: python, data-science, gis, postgis, psycopg2

I'm using a function to insert data to a PostGIS table using psycopg.

```
def shptoPosGIS(a,b,c):
  fieldRecord = """ insert into 'tablename' """
   
  fieldValue = (a,b,c)

  db_cursor.execute(fieldRecord, fieldValue)
  db_connection.commit()

for i in range (20000):
   shptoPostGIS(data["a"].iloc[i], 
                data["b"].iloc[i], 
                data["c"].iloc[i])
```

My Python script is inserting only two rows rather than 20000 to the PostGIS table. I'm guessing that the problem is related to synchronization. My for loop may run faster than the db_cursor.execute() method. Could anyone give a direction on how to solve this?

Comment: is it sufficient to commit after all the INSERTs?

Comment: @ti7 I commited after all inserts, but still inserting only two rows.

Comment: please include how you're creating your connection (specifically all the names you use which are missing! `db_cursor`, `db_connection`)

Comment: This isn't running asynchronously, so the loop can't run faster than the execute; as written the python code will wait for the execute to finish before moving on. Please give a fully working version of the code, as advised here; [mre]

Comment: This code won't work period: 1) `fieldRecord = """ insert into 'tablename' """` will fail. 2) `data` is never declared. 3) `shptoPostGIS` does not match `shptoPosGIS(a,b,c)`. I would say the failure is down to your demonstrated lack of attention to detail.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the problem. I had a date constraint UNIQUE and it was working just as it's supposed to.